# Release Windows File Handles During an Automated Build

Tags: windows, automation, filehandle

I have an automated build process that runs when no one in is in the office, and it pushes builds, deploys IIS web sites, and various other tasks. The problem is that if someone leaves a file open in one of these applications (like say they were looking at the web.config in a text editor), the build fails because it can't delete the files. I've seen people propose a solution as using Unlocker to release the file handles, but I don't want an interactive program - I want a command line application that I can call from the build process to release any open handles in the directory automatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Microsoft provide [handle.exe](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896655.aspx) which is a command-line tool.  You'd need to do some ninja parsing to interpret the output, though.  Also be aware that forcing a handle closed can have very unwelcome side-effects, it might actually be safer to kill the offending process.

Answer (score 0):

Build from a separate copy of the source code.  Leave the original copy for developers to inspect.

Comment: The problem isn't the source or the compilation - it's the deployment of the active sites. Developers need access to these, to view logs, temporarily change logging, etc, in the config files. The files have to be deleted and generated each build because they are generated configs and need to update if the template changed.

Comment: You could provide a managed way for developers to view files and check-in any necessary changes without allowing them to put locks on the files.  This would be a lot safer than trying to force the handles closed or killing the developer's processes.